# Android JSON: Unable to get response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to fetch a JSON response from OpenWeatherAPI to incorporate the current weather in my app. I have used volley to make a simple request to fetch the JSON response, but every time, I do not get the response. Instead, it always triggers the onErrorResponse method. What do I change to make this work?

I have added the uses Internet Permission in my manifest.

I have tried the solution to fetch JSON responses from many sources including the Official Android Developers Documentation, Other Questions from Stack Overflow, etc, but all of them failed.

I first used JSONObjectRequest instead of StringRequest, but even that did not provide me the results I required.

```
/*
    Create a request queue to fetch the JSONObject response.
*/
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));

/*
    JSON Object request.
*/
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No JSON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
queue.add(request);
```

I expect the Toast to show the response, but The Toast shows "No JSON".

Comment: try print out the error .  `Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: It says Bad URL, but I checked the URL thrice. When I go to that url in my browser, It returns the JSON text.

Comment: I got my answer. I had to add "https://". Thank you @JohnJoe

Comment: Use Retrofit.. it better performance than volley and updated...

Answer (score 0):

Add "https://" before your URL. You will get a response on your browser, but will not in Android.